# Converting Metal sheet to volumetric body

Tags: autodesk-fusion-360

I'm searching for a way to convert my sheet metal into a volumetric mesh or to copy it because I need it twice. I cant because fusion tells me that because its a metal sheet it cant be copyd.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Unfortunately this isn't a graphic design question.  CAD software is generally off-topic here. Sorry about that. You might want to try Engineering Stack Exchange instead.

Comment: This is a CAD application, make sure your question relates to **graphic design**. General questions on how to use Fusion 360 are likely to be off topic.